# list all defined constants from a file in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have some php files that includes some language constants

```
define("_SEARCH","Search");
define("_LOGIN","Login");
define("_WRITES","writes");
define("_POSTEDON","Posted on");
define("_NICKNAME","Nickname");
```

now I need to read each file and list all constants and their values

and to return an output like this :

constant name :
value is :

so I think there should be function to list all defined constants of a given php file.

I'm aware of functions like token_get_all or get_defined_constants but i wasn't able to do it.

Comment: What doesn't work if you're using `get_defined_constants()`?

Comment: i did noted that I have read those manuals , i'm concerning here on getting all defined constants of a ( specific PHP file ) not all defined constants of a system

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. Is there any other PHP Code/Content in those files?

Comment: maybe some lines which are comments but they are specified for language constants.

Comment: While I am sympathetic to this question, I wonder what the practical necessity is for figuring out constants defined in a specific file. As your project grows, you may want to put certain constant definitions into external files which are `include`d in another file, simply for readability without any change in functionality...

Comment: As far as I know, tokenizer (as you mentioned) would be the only way to do this. Where exactly did you struggle when trying this out?

Comment: I would rather prefix all constants in single file, with unique prefix. If you want avoid parsing the file via `preg_*` or similar methods

Comment: @deceze : I'm writing a language editing section. which i need to read every language file and show the defined constants to a user , and let him edit them as he prefers.

Answer (score 9):

If the files do contain nothing but `define` statements, you can use `get_defined_constants`:

```
function getUserDefinedConstants() {
    $constants = get_defined_constants(true);
    return (isset($constants['user']) ? $constants['user'] : array());  
}

$constantsBeforeInclude = getUserDefinedConstants();
include('file.php');
$constantsAfterInclude = getUserDefinedConstants();

$newConstants = array_diff_assoc($constantsAfterInclude, $constantsBeforeInclude);
```

What it does is basically: `get_defined_constants(true)` gives us an array of arrays with all available constants, sorted by sections (core, user, ..) - the array under the key 'user' gives us all user-defined constants that we defined in our php code using `define`, up to that point. `array_diff_assoc` gives us the difference between this array before and after the file got included.. and that is exactly a list of all constants that got defined in that specific file (as long as there is none of the declarations a duplicate, meaning a constant with that exact name has been defined before - but this would cause an error anyway).

Comment: but how to know that the before and after constant of a php file is "user" . please explain more on using this

Comment: yeah i agree with Mac, supposed that we are working with a framework and the constants in a file already included, we just can not 'exclude' the file and 're-include'

Comment: As these files are supposed to be language files, I doubt that they get included before. So no problem with that. @MacTaylor That 'user' there isn't the name of a single constant, it is the section where the constants belong (meaning they are "user"-defined and not by php itself). `$constants['user']` is an array of all constants you defined in your code via `define()`.

Comment: @NIKO Maybe too late, but...
One small correction, if you use `array_diff_assoc()` and assign as first value smaller array it will return empty `array()` so in this case we have to use: $newConstants = array_diff_assoc( $constantsAfterInclude, $constantsBeforeInclude );

Comment: @Jaglicic Thanks, good catch. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

this is the php script you need:

```
<?php
//remove comments
$Text  = php_strip_whitespace("your_constants_file.php"); 
$Text  = str_replace("<?php","",$Text);
$Text  = str_replace("<?","",$Text);
$Text  = str_replace("?>","",$Text);
$Lines = explode(";",$Text);
$Constants = array();

//extract constants from php code
foreach ($Lines as $Line) {    

  //skip blank lines
  if (strlen(trim($Line))==0) continue; 
  $Line  = trim($Line);

  //skip non-definition lines
  if (strpos($Line,"define(")!==0) continue;
  $Line  = str_replace("define(\"","",$Line);  

  //get definition name & value
  $Pos   = strpos($Line,"\",\"");
  $Left  = substr($Line,0,$Pos);
  $Right = substr($Line,$Pos+3);
  $Right = str_replace("\")","",$Right);

  $Constants[$Left] = $Right;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($Constants);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The result will be something similar to this:

```
array(5) {
  ["_SEARCH"]=>
  string(6) "Search"
  ["_LOGIN"]=>
  string(5) "Login"
  ["_WRITES"]=>
  string(6) "writes"
  ["_POSTEDON"]=>
  string(9) "Posted on"
  ["_NICKNAME"]=>
  string(8) "Nickname"
}
```

Comment: its a nice approach , but can we str_replace all comments like /* comments  */  and what's inside that?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game here but I had a similar issue. You could use an include() substitute/wrapper function that logs constants in an accessible global array.

```
<?php

function include_build_page_constants($file) {
    global $page_constants ;
    $before = get_defined_constants(true);
    include_once($file);
    $after = get_defined_constants(true);
    if ( isset($after['user']) ) {
        if ( isset($before['user']) ) {
            $current = array_diff_assoc($after['user'],$before['user']);
        }else{
            $current = $after['user'];
        }
        $page_constants[basename($file)]=$current;
    }
}

include_and_build_page_constants('page1.php');
include_and_build_page_constants('page2.php');

// test the array
echo '<pre>'.print_r($page_constants,true).'</pre>';

?>
```

This will result in something like:

```
Array
(
    [page1.php] => Array
        (
            [_SEARCH] => Search
            [_LOGIN] => Login
            [_WRITES] => writes
            [_POSTEDON] => Posted on
            [_NICKNAME] => Nickname
        )

    [page2.php] => Array
        (
            [_THIS] => Foo
            [_THAT] => Bar
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do this on runtime, you should take a look at [PHP Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), specifically at the [ReflectionClass::getConstants()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) which lets you do exactly what you seem to want.

Comment: he is defining constants using 'define', not using 'const' keyword. and also not in a class

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same problem. I went from jondinham's suggestion, but I prefer to use regex, as it is a bit easier to control and flexible. Here's my version of the solution:

```
$text = php_strip_whitespace($fileWithConstants);
$text = str_replace(array('<?php', '<?', '?>'), '', $text);
$lines = explode(";", $text);
$constants = array();

//extract constants from php code
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    //skip blank lines
    if (strlen(trim($line)) == 0)
        continue;

    preg_match('/^define\((\'.*\'|".*"),( )?(.*)\)$/', trim($line), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if ($matches) {
        $constantName = substr($matches[1][0], 1, strlen($matches[1][0]) - 2);
        $constantValue = $matches[3][0];
        $constants[$constantName] = $constantValue;
    }
}
print_r($constants);
```

Comment: Great answer, but I think it's to another question. I'd git you a +1 it will be misleading in this case. Your answer suites more to this question -> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/site-redirecting-to-wp-signup-php/165509

But thanks, you helped me out :)